# Why neo4j cypher expression exists(() --> (n)) evaluates to false when actually it is true?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have such a graph
[image]

Each node has unique `nodeId` property which is guarantied by Neo4j constraints.
Each relationships has unique `id` property.
Version of neo4j is 4.3.7.

Light green nodes are companies, pink nodes are people and other nodes are additional info which cannot be stored inside a node.
Here, "Peter company" has 2 charges, primary address, secondary address, date of creation and date of termination.

I would like to remove old information from "Peter company" and its director. For this I am using such a query:

```
UNWIND $batch AS data 
MATCH (n:Entity { nodeId: data.entityId }) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[rel]->(prop:Property) 
WHERE NOT prop.nodeId IN data.propertyIds
DELETE rel
WITH prop
WHERE NOT exists(()-->(prop))
DELETE prop
```

where `$batch` in this example is

```
[
    {
        'entityId':    '0000',
        'propertyIds': ['0002', '0003', '0004', '0005', '0006', '0009']
    },
    {
        'entityId':    '0001',
        'propertyIds': ['0004', '0010']
    },
]
```

`entityId` is `nodeId` of a node and `propertyIds` are `nodeId` of current additional information (properties).
If there is a connection from entity to a property which ID is not in `propertyIds`, then this is an old information, and edge between them must be removed. In addition, if after that a property has no more incoming edges (it can have only incoming), it is deleted.

The list above contains IDs of company and its director and IDs of their current properties.
A date that has a connection to "Other company" is obsolete to "Peter Company" and its `nodeId` is not present in the batch above. As a result of the query I expect that connection from the company to old property must be removed while the property is not deleted.

But I got an error:

```
Cannot delete node<18>, because it still has relationships. To delete this node, you must first delete its relationships.
```

Why I am getting an error? Node 18 has an incoming connection from "Other company", and thus `exists(()-->(prop))` must return `true`.

If I change that expression to `exists(()--(prop))`, I get no error.

If I replace `DELETE` with `SET` in a query:

```
UNWIND $batch AS data 
MATCH (n:Entity { nodeId: data.entityId }) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[rel]->(prop:Property) 
WHERE NOT prop.nodeId IN data.propertyIds
SET rel.toPrune = true
WITH prop
WHERE NOT exists(()-->(prop))
SET prop.toPrune = true
```

Then relationship is marked while node is not, i. e., `exists(()-->(prop))` returned `true`.

I created an example in Python that reproduces the problem:

```py
from neo4j import GraphDatabase

with GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost:7687", auth=('neo4j', 'neo')) as driver, \
        driver.session() as session:

    create_graph = """
    MERGE (n1:Test:Entity:Company {nodeId: "0000"}) SET n1.name = "Peter company"
    MERGE (n2:Test:Entity:Person {nodeId: "0001"}) SET n2.name = "Peter"
    MERGE (n3:Test:Property:Charge {nodeId: "0002"}) SET n3.status = "closed"
    MERGE (n4:Test:Property:Charge {nodeId: "0003"}) SET n4.status = "opened"
    MERGE (n5:Test:Property:Address {nodeId: "0004"}) SET n5.country = "France"
    MERGE (n6:Test:Property:Address {nodeId: "0005"})
        SET n6.country = "France"
        SET n6.city = "Ham Les Varennes"
    MERGE (n7:Test:Property:Date {nodeId: "0006"})
        SET n7.date = datetime("2014-09-04T00:00:00")
        SET n7.monthIsKnown = true
        SET n7.dayIsKnown = true
    MERGE (n8:Test:Property:Date {nodeId: "0007"})
        SET n8.date = datetime("1962-01-01T00:00:00")
        SET n8.monthIsKnown = false
        SET n8.dayIsKnown = false
    MERGE (n9:Test:Entity:Company {nodeId: "0008"}) SET n9.name = "Other company"
    MERGE (n10:Test:Property:Date {nodeId: "0009"})
        SET n10.date = datetime("1962-01-01T00:00:00")
        SET n10.monthIsKnown = false
        SET n10.dayIsKnown = false
    MERGE (n11:Test:Property:Date {nodeId: "0010"})
        SET n11.date = datetime("1976-01-01T00:00:00")
        SET n11.monthIsKnown = false
        SET n11.dayIsKnown = false
    
    MERGE (n1)-[:HAS_CHARGE {id: 1}]->(n3)
    MERGE (n1)-[:HAS_CHARGE {id: 2}]->(n4)
    MERGE (n1)-[:HAS_PRIMARY_ADDRESS {id: 3}]->(n5)
    MERGE (n1)-[:HAS_SECONDARY_ADDRESS {id: 4}]->(n6)
    MERGE (n1)-[:HAS_TERMINATION_DATE {id: 5}]->(n7)
    MERGE (n1)-[:HAS_CREATION_DATE {id: 6}]->(n8)
    MERGE (n1)-[:HAS_CREATION_DATE {id: 7}]->(n10)
    
    MERGE (n2)-[:FR_DIRECTOR {id: 8}]->(n1)
    MERGE (n2)-[:HAS_COUNTRY_OF_RESIDENCE {id: 9}]->(n5)
    MERGE (n2)-[:HAS_DATE_OF_BIRTH {id: 10}]->(n11)
    
    MERGE (n9)-[:HAS_CREATION_DATE {id: 11}]->(n8)
    """

    with session.begin_transaction() as tx:
        tx.run(create_graph)

    batch = [
        {
            'entityId':    '0000',
            'propertyIds': ['0002', '0003', '0004', '0005', '0006', '0009']
            },
        {
            'entityId':    '0001',
            'propertyIds': ['0004', '0010']
            },
        ]

    clean_old_properties = """
    UNWIND $batch AS data 
    MATCH (n:Entity { nodeId: data.entityId }) 
    OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[rel]->(prop:Property) 
    WHERE NOT prop.nodeId IN data.propertyIds
    DELETE rel
    WITH prop
    WHERE NOT exists(()-->(prop))
    DELETE prop
    """

    with session.begin_transaction() as tx:
        tx.run(clean_old_properties, dict(batch=batch))
```

An interesting note: if both queries in this example are executed in one transaction, then no error emitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused by a bug inside Neo4j kernel. It was fixed in version 4.4.12.

> **Kernel**
>
> - Fix node degree calculation when relationships are removed in the same transaction

[Changelog](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j-4.4-changelog#4412)

[Related issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/12909)